# Why do i not get through to my Meteor.method on the server?

Tags: mongodb, collections, meteor, meteorite

I'm trying to add a url to the logged in users collection. My final goal at least is to be able to add a field e.g `{profilePicture: 'http://randompic.com/123.png'}`

What i've tried so far is:

```
<template name="profile">
  <h1>My Profile</h1>
  <form class="form-inline"action="">
    <label for="url"></label>
    <input class="input input-large" type="url" name="url" placeholder="URL for you image..." id="url">
    <button class="btn btn-success submit">Update profile picture</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

When the user will press the Update profile picture -button i send it to this helper function:

```
Template.profile.events({
  'click .submit': function (evt, tmpl) {
    var userid = Meteor.userId();
    var url = tmpl.find('#url').value;
    var options = {_id: userid, profilePicture: url};
    Meteor.call('addToProfile', options);
  }
});
```

I have tried to alert out option._id and options.profilePicture and i have that data availble.
Now when i pass it along to my server.js file i get no output of my alert:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'addToProfile': function(options) {

  //Not even this alert will show.. 

    alert(options._id);    Edit: console.log() works on the server thought.
  } 
})
```

So that is my first issue.

The second problem (to come) is that i don't know how to update/add to the users collection with this profilePicture data. Would really appreciate if someone could contribute with a small example of that part.

Comment: is alert() a function on the server?  I think you might want `console.log( options._id )`.

Comment: Yeah,i think alert is not a server side function.You can try `consoloe.log()` and u can see the log in terminal

Comment: You can update the user coll using `Meteor.user.update` example `Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.user()._id}, {$set:{"profile.name":"XXXX"}})`

Comment: I do get the console.log() to giv me some output, but not in the chrome console, but in the terminal... :)

Comment: @getJETsetTER Yea, the methods are evaluated on the server, where `console.log` prints the arguments to the terminal, so everything works as expected. But you don't really need a method to update a document in a collection, just do as iAmME (kind of) wrote.

Comment: @PeppeL-G But my template (profile) is in the client, and i have insecure and autopublish uninstalled, but are you saying that i can update the user collection anyway? I tried it like this now (no Meteor.method): `Template.profile.events({
  'click .submit': function (evt, tmpl) {
    var url = tmpl.find('#url').value;
    Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.user()._id}, {$set:{"profilePicture":url}})
  }
});` But it did not stick...

Comment: You can still update documents even though you don't have them on the client. However, if you have removed the insecure package, you have to add a `Collection.allow` rule that returns `true` for the update to be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments everything seems to be functioning as expected. It appears that you are just trying to update some user data on the client. Since you have the `insecure` package removed you need to validate the updates on the server (that the client requests), this is how you would do that:

```
// only applies to client requests
Meteor.users.allow({
    // validation for user inserts
    insert: function ( userId, doc ) {

        // perform any checks on data that you want to perform, like checking to see if the current user is an admin.

        // this check just requests that a user be logged in
        return userId;
    }
    , 
    // is your validation for user updates
    update: function ( userId, doc, fields, modifier ) {

        // again, perform any validation you want. A typical check is to make sure they didn't add any extra fields.

        // this makes sure a user is logged in and that they are only attempting to update themself
        return userId === doc._id;
    }
});
```

There are some more thorough examples in the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow). Now you can just call update like you normally would and rely on the server to perform any validation!